# JSON Object get problem

Tags: android

Hy!

I have a Json Object:

```
                            HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
                            HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
                            final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                            Log.e("test", jObject.toString());
```

Log:

```
{"responseData":null,"responseStatus":200,"responseDetails":null}
```

Code:

```
Log.e("test", String.valueOf(jObject.getInt("responseStatus")))`;
```

Log:

```
200
```

Get Int from Json:

```
                                    if (jObject.getInt("responseStatus")== 200)
                                {
                                    Toast toast ;
                                    toast =     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", 500);
                                toast.show();
                                    finish();
                                }
 else
                                {
                                    Log.e("else", "else");
                                    //dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
                                     if (jObject.getInt("responseStatus")== 500)
                                     {
                                         throw new Exception("Server Error");
                                     }
                                     else if (jObject.getInt("responseStatus")== 400)
                                     {
                                         throw new Exception("Wrong User/Password");
                                     }
                                     else
                                     {
                                         throw new Exception();
                                     }
                                }
                              //pd.dismiss(); 


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("catch", "catch");
                             Toast toast ;
                                toast =     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), 500);
                            toast.show();

                        }
```

Log:

```
 catch
 Value null at responseData of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

The log says that the responeStatus is 200, but the toast and the finish was not executed

Please help

full code:

```
package com.android.skiptvad;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Registerusr extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.regusr);
        Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reguserreq);
        final EditText user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reguseruser);
        final EditText pw = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reguserpw);
        final EditText email  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.requseremail);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (user.getText() != null && pw.getText()!= null && email.getText()!= null)
                {
                    download(user.getText().toString(), md5(pw.getText().toString()), email.getText().toString());
                }

            }
        });
    }
    public void download (final String usr, final String pw, final String email)
    {

            try{
                            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                            String postURL = "http://surfkid.redio.de/register";
                            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
                                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", usr));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pw));
                              params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country_id", "1"));
                                UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
                                post.setEntity(ent);

                                HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
                                HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
                                final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                                Log.e("test", jObject.toString());
                                Log.e("test", String.valueOf(jObject.getInt("responseStatus")));

                                //JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject("responseData");

                                if (jObject.getInt("responseStatus")== 200)
                                {

                                    finish();
                                }


                                else
                                {
                                    Log.e("else", "else");
                                    //dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
                                     if (jObject.getInt("responseStatus")== 500)
                                     {
                                         throw new Exception("Server Error");
                                     }
                                     else if (jObject.getInt("responseStatus")== 400)
                                     {
                                         throw new Exception("Wrong User/Password");
                                     }
                                     else
                                     {
                                         throw new Exception();
                                     }
                                }
                              //pd.dismiss(); 


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("catch", "catch");
                             Toast toast ;
                                toast =     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), 500);
                            toast.show();
                            Log.e("catch", e.getMessage());

                        }




    }
    private String md5(String in) {

        MessageDigest digest;

        try {

            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

            digest.reset();        

            digest.update(in.getBytes());

            byte[] a = digest.digest();

            int len = a.length;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len << 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                sb.append(Character.forDigit((a[i] & 0xf0) >> 4, 16));

                sb.append(Character.forDigit(a[i] & 0x0f, 16));

            }

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: By putting the network calls in the main UI thread you risk getting Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and Android killing your app. You'll want to do all network communication in a thread, look into AsyncTask or Handler

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your code you had commented                         `//JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject("responseData");`

after this did you get the catch log that you have mentioned " Value null at responseData of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
"

because, doing a getJsonObject over a null value is not possible.

you would have to do it this way.

```
Object menuObject = jObject.get("responseData");

if(menuObject == JSONObject.NULL)
{
 // Skip processing the response Data
}
```

Comment: What if I would like to parse the rest of the data instead of skipping the remaining part, which contains valuable information for me?

Answer (score 1):

I realize I'm a little late to the party but Sethu is correct.  I knew I needed to test for null, but the following wouldn't work:

```
if(Object.get("responseData") != null)
```

But the following works fine:

```
if(Object.get("responseData") != JSONObject.NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```
toast =     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", 500);
```

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29) the `int duration` is:

> `duration`     How long to display the message. Either `LENGTH_SHORT` or `LENGTH_LONG`

Try changing the line to:

```
toast =     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Comment: if i delete the toast the finish also won't be executed

Comment: If you fix the toast (or replace it with a Log output) does the code block execute?  The problem is either that the code block isn't getting executed, or that the `finish()` isn't doing as you expect.

Comment: the problem is the last log post the code access the catch block because the parsing error

Comment: Post the line of code that displays the single "200" entry in the log.  Can't you store that result and test it rather than calling `getInt` in your `if` statement?

Comment: So is the behaviour that even when the log prints "200" it then continues into the `else` statement and executes that code block? Or is it that it matches the 200 and executes the block with `finish()` but doesn't actually end your app?  A concise description of the problem would help.

Comment: ok sorry man first thanks for your help.... the debugger doesn'T enter the else block. i think that the debugger goes to the if statement and want to find the responseStatus and there he notice that there is something wrong with the responseData and the value null

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace please?

Answer (score -2):

Try removing the Toast and the finish and just logging access into that IF statement - it might be a situation where Android doesnt display the Toast because its already in the process of finishing the Activity (although this seems unlikely since Android in other times seems happy to display Toasts for Activities that have already left the foreground)